# OPENJSON, parse JSON response

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can anybody help me out with using T-SQL OPENJSON to parse this JSON response?

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(Edm.String)",
"value": [
  "d4eec69a-98fe-4d83-865e-29769172948b",
  "4a2e47ce-d135-4078-ac50-7d5520f17317"
]
}
```

What I want is to have the array values returned.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just specify the `json_path` to `value` in the `OPENJSON` function:

```
SELECT value 
FROM OPENJSON ( @json, '$.value' )
```

**Output:**

```
value
------------------------------------
d4eec69a-98fe-4d83-865e-29769172948b
4a2e47ce-d135-4078-ac50-7d5520f17317
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you kind help! :)